Hillshade not correctly generated using QGIS
I'm learning QGIS with QGIS Training Manual resources (https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/terrain_analysis.html). I'm working on 7.3.1 Follow Along: Calculating a Hillshade. The instructions are as follows:

I followed the instructions but it failed and I got this:
QGIS version: 3.28.15-Firenze
QGIS code revision: 252ad49ddcb
Qt version: 5.15.2
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.3.2
GEOS version: 3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2
PROJ version: Rel. 8.1.1, September 1st, 2021
PDAL version: 2.3.0 (git-version: Release)
Algorithm started at: 2024-05-12T12:04:34
Algorithm 'Hillshade' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'AZIMUTH' : 300, 'INPUT' : '/Users/memeglic/Desktop/QGIS practices/QGIS-Training-Data-release_3.28/exercise_data/raster/SRTM/srtm_41_19.tif', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'V_ANGLE' : 40, 'Z_FACTOR' : 1 }
Execution completed in 0.03 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/private/var/folders/pw/rrv443d10clcfcvyx5vpl86r0000gn/T/processing_ISKAZS/4b24b54d216448ebbb10a091d3855b56/OUTPUT.nc'}
Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• /private/var/folders/pw/rrv443d10clcfcvyx5vpl86r0000gn/T/processing_ISKAZS/4b24b54d216448ebbb10a091d3855b56/OUTPUT.nc
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
What should I do?

Try saving the output as a .tif file

Go to Settings -> Options -> Processing -> General and set default output raster layer extension to "tif" and re-run your hillshade.

